# Cambiar color datagridviewbutton

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Buenas estoy haciendo un formulario en C#. Cuando otra ventana me devuelve un `dialog.result.OK` quiero que cambie el color de fondo del botón del `DataGridView`, en este caso a verde alguna solución sencilla?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncell(VS.80).aspx) (Lamento que la documentación de MSDN esté en inglés, pero no conseguí la versión en Español)

> Cuando los estilos visuales están habilitados, los botones en una
>   columna de botón se pintan utilizando un ButtonRenderer, y los estilos
>   de celda especificados a través de propiedades como DefaultCellStyle
>   no tienen ningún efecto.

Tenés 2 opciones, una, sería eliminar de tu `Program.cs` la línea

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

que provocaría que un cambio como

```
row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

sea funcional, pero lo demás no se vería de la mejor manera, la otra opción, sería heredar de `DataGridViewButtonCell` sobreescribiendo el método `Paint()`, puedes usar el método `static` **DrawButton** de la clase **ButtonRenderer** para pintar el boton vos mismo, eso implica, detectar y pintar en que estado se encuentra (`hover`, `clicked`, etc), es factible, pero es un trabajo GIGANTE

Sin embargo, acá te dejo un código para que puedas empezar

```
 //Custom ButonCell
 public class MyButtonCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
    {
        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, cellBounds, formattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Comic Sans MS", 9.0f, FontStyle.Bold), true, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Default);
        }
    }
```

Este sería un `DataGridView` de prueba

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn c = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            c.CellTemplate = new MyButtonColumn();
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(c);
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Click Me");
```

Lo que hace este ejemplo, es agregar un botón con la fuente *Comic Sans MS*, sin importar si está en `hover`, `clicked`, etc

Aclaro, que esta respuesta, está basada en la [respuesta de BFree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586829/change-color-of-button-in-datagridview-cell) en StackOverflow en Inglés

Un consejo personal para tu caso en particular, yo, utilizaría `DataGridViewImageColumn` que tiene una usabilidad un poco más amigable

Saludos y éxitos!